# Lock at the time of Inserting record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have windows service have two method which are inserting data to the same table at the same time.but at the time of insert it threw the exception.how i can make lock on such situation.

thank you in advance

Comment: If all you're doing is inserting new data, many processes inserting at the same time should not result in an exception. Are you sure you're not doing something else that might be causing it?

Comment: what is the exception? what are the queries?

Answer (score 0):

if its update statement, i would suggest BEGIN TRANSACTION with READ COMMIITED isolation level. but since its insert, u might want to create extra table act like a queue. Insert everything in new table and after that u can run your validation.